# Discrete Probability - Probability of Completing a race

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A heroic somebody has decided they want to try to complete a Superman race. They will stop trying if they complete the race or after three attempts. The probability of completing the race in one attempt is 1/3 and that these attempts are independent. Determine the probability that this somebody will complete the race.

Does anybody know how to attempt this question please?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the opposite probability that they fail to complete the race in any of their three allotted attempts.

Comment: So then for each attempt the probability they do not finish is 2/3?? I am honestly very lost right now sorry.

Comment: is the answer roughly 70% by any chance?

Comment: @learning_maniac failing the first time occurs with probability $\frac{2}{3}$.  Also failing the second time would occur again with probability $\frac{2}{3}$ and so we multiply these giving $\frac{4}{9}$ to have failed both of the first two times.  Failing again the third time we multiply by another $\frac{2}{3}$ giving $\frac{8}{27}$.  Subtracting this away from $1$ gives the probability of success at least once in those three as being $1-\frac{8}{27}\approx 0.7037$